# index() function not returning the correct indices

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of numbers, and I want to print the indices of each of the elements using a for loop.

```
test = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4]

for x in test:
    print(test.index(x))
```

When I run the code, it prints "0 1 1 3 3" instead of "0 1  2 3 4." What is happening here?

Comment: Please read the docs and see what `index` is doing. You are looking for `enumerate(test)`

Comment: when you do for x in test, you'll get the numbers 1, 2, 2, 4, 4...
the index function returns the *first* index of the provided value -> 0, 1, 1, 3, 3

Comment: Elements of a list don't "know" that they are elements of a list, and especially not *which* element. In fact, the two ``2``s and two ``4``s are each *exactly the same* object, literally being at two positions. This is not unlike how objects don't "know" if and what name they have, and how objects can have 1, zero, or many names.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Documentation for Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) you can find out how `index` operates. This code is preforming correctly because `index` returns the first index with the value that's passed into the method

So in your code, with repeated values in the list, the second time both `1` and `3` are printed is because the first instance of `2` and `4`, respectively, are positioned at those indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4]

for index, x in enumerate(test):
    print(index, x)
```